# How to know which header file my project is useing while building code

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

in my project we are using zlib.h header file.
I have one in zlib.h in my standard C headers. I want to know which file my project is using .
Is there any flag to run with make to get the over log?

Comment: It is a bit weird your question, but you can do a `gcc wahtever > outputfile.txt` and check the whole compilation output, calmly.

Comment: Are you trying to find out which file is including `zlib.h`?  If so have a look at the [`-H`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options).

Comment: G.M , I want to know which zlib.h file is including in my project ?

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is specific to `gcc`, you can try -

```
gcc -E your_project_file.c
```

You can pipe the output to less or redirect this  to a file.

Now in the output search for `zlib.h`, you will see the full path of the file included.

Comment: Hi Ajay, Can we add this in our make files to get detailed log?